# How to place back caret after a text insert?

Tags: javascript, froala

I'm doing a text expander functionality. Basically if I insert something like "HW" the code will detect "Hello World" and insert that into the editor.

How do I set the caret after my text? I only found methods to set selection that take a node, but this doesn't quite apply. In other editors like Redactor there is a unicode character that can be added to the string so the editor knows where the caret should be.

How to do this with Froala?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do that in Froala Editor by using markers. If you would like to place cursor between Hello and World when you insert the HTML, you could do it like this:

```js
$(selector).froalaEditor('html.insert', 'Hello ' + $.FroalaEditor.MARKERS + 'World');
```

Comment: Nice to see the mantainer answering about the project! I will check your suggestion, just wanted to give that `+1` for now.